Consultas Mescladas Retornando diferente do esperado - Power BI
Estou criando um relatório de RH, onde tenho que filtrar o usuário logado (gestor), e filtrar apenas as suas seções.
Para filtrar o usuário logado, faço através de uma função criada, como na imagem abaixo, retornando de uma lista de gestores, apenas o logado:
{[Usuario] =  LEFT( username(), SEARCH("@", username(), 1, LEN(username()))-1) || [Usuario] =  SUBSTITUTE(username(), "RS-SEBRAE\", "")}

Imagem com função
Para listar as seções, mesclei cada consulta com a lista de gestores, que filtrei acima. Assim, deveria retornar apenas os dados após o filtro. Mas o filtro parece ser executado apenas após a mesclagem das consultas, como podemos ver abaixo:
Retorno Consultas
Na imagem, o Usuário Logado retorna apenas o gestor logado, como previsto. A Seção Logada, deveria ser filtrada a partir do Usuário Logado, trazendo registros apenas em que a coluna Chapa Gestor fossem iguais a coluna Chapa Colaborador da tabela Usuário Logado.
No caso a mesclagem não está ocorrendo após o filtro do gestor. Na imagem 2 dá para ver que a coluna Chapa Gestor está trazendo valores diferentes da coluna Chapa Colaborador, que é fonte da mesclagem.
No relatório em questão, tenho duas tabelas (RH_PONTO_DIM_COLABORADOR e RH_PONTO_DIM_SECAO).
Na tabela RH_PONTO_DIM_COLABORADOR, filtro via expressão DAX o usuário que está logado no momento (quem está vizualizando o relatório).
Já na tabela RH_PONTO_DIM_SECAO, realizo uma mescla com a tabela RH_PONTO_DIM_COLABORADOR, com o tipo de junção interna (onde deveria filtrar os dados que obrigatóriamente contenham nas duas tabelas). Segue na imagem abaixo:
inserir a descrição da imagem aqui
O problema acontece que a tabela RH_PONTO_DIM_COLABORADOR está sendo filtrada corretamente, mas a tabela RH_PONTO_DIM_SECAO traz todos os registros como se a mesclagem não tivesse ocorrido.

Não repita perguntas, revise/edite a pergunta orientação, se estiver dentro do escopo ela será avaliada na fila de analises por diferentes usuários para uma possível abertura.
